# Ctypes array return elements as str not char pointers

Tags: python, c, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I am trying to create a ctypes array which has char pointers as elements

First I initialize char pointers to normal python list

```
from ctypes import *
array = []
for i in range(5):
    array.append(c_char_p("Hello World "+str(i)))
```

When I print element type in list using `print type(array[0])` the output is a pointer `<class 'ctypes.c_char_p'>`

then I convert the list to c array

```
carray = (c_char_p * len(array))(*array)
```

and when I print type of element in carray using `print type(carray[0])` its a `<type 'str'>`

I expected the carray to return a `char pointer` but it returned a `str`.

why and how can i get `char pointer` from `carray`

Comment: why do you need `type(carray[0]) == ctypes.c_char_p`? Does it fail if you pass `carray` as a parameter to a C function via `ctypes` (without `c_char_p()`)?

Comment: I am not passing this to any function. I was just checking out ctypes to using in a project. I was just curious that it returned a string rather than a a char pointer and I wanted to know why.

Comment: look at [the table that shows how ctypes, C, Python types are related](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)